# power series expansion of the function $ e^{-\frac {1}{x^2}} $ about $0 $

Tags: real-analysis

I know that the function $e^{-\frac {1}{x^2}}$ is infinite  differentiable in a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Does a power series representation exist for this function? If it does not exist, please provide some explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ if $x\ne 0$, and let $f(0)=0$. All the derivatives of $f$ at $0$ are $0$.

The function $f$  has a delightfully simple Maclaurin series. The series happens to converge to $f$ only at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

It does have a nice Laurent series about zero, doesn't it? That is a power series representation, isn't it? (Just substitute $z=-\frac1{x^2}$ in the Maclaurin series for $e^z$).

Answer (score 0):

That $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n$ needs a proof.

Given a polynomial $p$, can you show that $$\lim_{x\to0}p(1/x)e^{-1/x^2}=0?$$

---

A comment on the peculiar example, the function is very useful (read *important*) in distribution theory where one needs functions that are infinitely continuously differentiable and vanish outside a bounded set.